# tvOS - Reset CollectionView's focus at one point of time with remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, collectionview, focus-engine

I have a setup a collection view with `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` set to true.

CollectionView is designed such a way that it has nested collection views,

```
CollectionView 
  -> Section 1
    --->Header
    --->Cell nested with collectionview 
  -> Section 2
    --->Header
    --->Cell nested with collectionview 
....so on....
```

There is pagination too.

Now if user scrolls to say 2nd item in 7th section and clicks menu in tv remote, I am scrolling collection to top. [either by setting content offset to 0 or scrolling to 0th index]

**Requirement**: After scrolling to 0th index, if user tries to focus on first cell in 0th section, I want focus to be at 0th index.

**Issue**: But now collection view remembers last focused index path and scrolls to 2nd item in 7th section.

**Expected**: I do not want collection view to remember the last focused index path in this case. In all other cases, it should be remembered. i.e, after scrolling to top, I want do something like

```
collectionView.scrollToTop()
resetFocus() //which should reset collection view's focus to initial index.


func resetFocus() { 
//What should be written here to reset the focus of collection view.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try also implementing `indexPathForPreferredFocusedView` after you reset focus. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618066-indexpathforpreferredfocusedview).